How to allow Custom User Meta using a Simple JWT plugin in WordPress
I'm trying to implement JWT Authentication on my WordPress website and allow a React Native app to register new users.
I want to add custom user meta but it's not working properly.
I added custom meta into plugin settings in WordPress.

Then following documentation I made axios request:
const options = {
                          method: 'POST',
                          url: 'XXX',
                          params: {
                            rest_route: '/simple-jwt-login/v1/users',
                            email: email,
                            password: password,
                            AUTH_KEY: 'XXX',
                            user_login: username,
                            display_name: imeIPrezime.split(" ")[0],
                            first_name:  imeIPrezime.split(" ")[0],
                            user_meta:`{”tel”:"${tel}", ”adresa”:"${adresa}"}`
                          },
                          headers: {
                            cookie: 'PHPSESSID=XXX',
                            'User-Agent': 'insomnia/8.6.1'
                          }
                        };

                        console.log(options.params.user_meta);
                        
                        axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
                          console.log(response.data);
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                          console.error(error.response.data);
                        });

I also tried multiple things to add via a plugin in wordpress
First i tried this
// Register custom user meta fields
function NKWP_register_custom_user_meta_fields() {
    register_meta('user', 'tel', [
        'type' => 'string',
        'description' => 'Custom Field Description',
        'single' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true, // Expose field in REST API
    ]);
    register_meta('user', 'adresa', [
        'type' => 'string',
        'description' => 'Custom Field Description',
        'single' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true, // Expose field in REST API
    ]);
}
add_action('init', 'NKWP_register_custom_user_meta_fields');

// Expose custom user meta field in REST API
function NKWP_expose_tel() {
    register_rest_field('user', 'tel', [
        'get_callback' => 'NKWP_get_tel',
        'schema' => null,
    ]);
}

function NKWP_get_tel($user, $request) {
    return get_user_meta($user['id'], "tel", true);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'NKWP_expose_tel');

// Expose custom user meta field in REST API
function NKWP_expose_adresa() {
    register_rest_field('user', 'adresa', [
        'get_callback' => 'NKWP_get_adresa',
        'schema' => null,
    ]);
}

function NKWP_get_adresa($user, $request) {
    return get_user_meta($user['id'], "adresa", true);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'NKWP_expose_adresa');
add_action('rest_api_init', 'NKWP_expose_tel');

Then i tried just registering the keys
// Register custom user meta fields
function NKWP_register_custom_user_meta_fields() {
    register_meta('user', 'tel', [
        'type' => 'string',
        'description' => 'Custom Field Description',
        'single' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true, // Expose field in REST API
    ]);
    register_meta('user', 'adresa', [
        'type' => 'string',
        'description' => 'Custom Field Description',
        'single' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true, // Expose field in REST API
    ]);
}
add_action('init', 'NKWP_register_custom_user_meta_fields');

Registering goes trough with either of those as well as with neither of them.
Only difference is when I have a plugin side code activated I get this response
{
    "id": 102,
    "username": "xxx",
    "name": "xxx",
    "first_name": "xxx",
    "last_name": "",
    "email": "xxx",
    "url": "",
    "description": "",
    "link": "xxx",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "nickname": "xxx",
    "slug": "xxx",
    "roles": [
        "contributor"
    ],
    "registered_date": "2024-04-10T20:30:06+00:00",
    "capabilities": {
        "edit_posts": true,
        "read": true,
        "level_1": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "delete_posts": true,
        "contributor": true
    },
    "extra_capabilities": {
        "contributor": true
    },
    "avatar_urls": {
        "24": "https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/9e725502ed014083cb676aceb2c79f21?s=24&d=mm&r=g",
        "48": "https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/9e725502ed014083cb676aceb2c79f21?s=48&d=mm&r=g",
        "96": "https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/9e725502ed014083cb676aceb2c79f21?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
    },
    "meta": {
        "persisted_preferences": [],
        "tel": "",
        "adresa": ""
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "xxx"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    }
}

and without the difference is in meta field
    "meta": {
        "persisted_preferences": [],
    
    },


The issue was recently resolved. Simply update the plugin, and it should work fine.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
